# Get the destination element attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So I use Jquery UI Sortable and want to get attributes of the current item **being replaced**.
Found only one solution - call a prev(), but it returns one located above element, which may not exists and element ID is taken from a stored in database values.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>item 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>item 3</td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>



$("tbody").sortable({
    update:function(ev,ui){
        var item = ui.item.attr("id");
        var replaced = ui.item.prev().attr("id"); // If drag to 1 return "undefined"
            alert("Moved #" + item + " to #" + replaced);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qL6t7Lo7/

Answer (score 0):

Update your replaced variable to:

```
var replaced = ui.item.prev().attr("id") || 1;
```

The reson you were getting undefined is because the first element doesnt have a previous item. But because this can only happen on the first item you can store `replaced` as 1 if no `ui.item.prev().attr("id")` was found.